# $\frac{1}{\sin^2(t)}\frac{d}{dt}\sin^2(t)\frac{d}{dt}f=-k(k+2)f$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the differential equation $$\frac{1}{\sin^2(t)}\frac{d}{dt}\left(\sin^2(t)\frac{d}{dt}f\right)=-k(k+2)f.$$ I know that (multiples of) $\frac{\sin((k+1)t)}{\sin(t)}$ are a solution but there have to be more solutions than this since the differential equation is of order two or am I wrong here?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: For clarification; $f$ is also a function of $t$ I guess? Is the partial differential operator really needed here or can you replace it by $\frac{d}{dt}$ since it is not sure whether this is a differential equation or a partial differential euqation; further you tagged it  only with "differential-equations"? Does the differential operator infront of the squared sine ist to be read as $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\sin^2(t)\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f\right)$ or as $\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\sin^2(t)\right)\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f\right)$?

Comment: $f$ is a function of $t$, yes. Also you can replace the partials with straight $dt$'s. The squared sine is to be read as the first way you suggested. I hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another linearly independent solution is
$$
\frac{\cos((k+1)t)}{\sin(t)}.
$$
You can find it using the method of reduction of order. The change
$$
f(x)=\frac{\sin((k+1)t)}{\sin(t)}\,g(x)
$$
will lead to a first order equation.

Another possibility is the change
$$
g(t)=\frac{f(t)}{\sin t},
$$
which leads to a second order equation with constant coefficients.

Comment: Okay I will calculate this. But on $[0,\pi]$ the only solutions are multiples of $\frac{\sin((q+1)t)}{\sin(t)}$ since this is defined in $t=0$ and the other solutions aren't. Am I seeing this correctly?

Comment: The equation is not defined on $[0,\pi]$. On $(0,\pi)$ there are two linearly independent solutions.